# Do verified Terraform modules still exist? The verified badge appears to be missing

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

Just exploring the use of Terraform modules. According to the documentation, I should be able to see a "verified" flag on modules that can be some what more trusted. But I can't see these on any of modules I have looked at.

Documentation regarding verified modules:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/registry/modules/verified

Example:
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/nomad/aws/latest

Comment: Verified modules are maintained by partners, and partners generally only maintain providers. The specific example you linked towards would not be verified as it is maintained by Gruntwork, and they are not the company associated with AWS or Nomad.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks for the clarification. So it is likely there are very few if any verified modules? And you could possibly argue it's safer to use the verified providers directly.

Comment: "safer" is a word with various different meanings for different contexts and people. There are multiple areas to evaluate a module against that also vary in importance depending on the circumstances. You would probably want to evaluate on a case-by-case basis using your own experience.